# What grid/view does Instagram use for the feed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, user-interface, instagram

I'm in the process of emulating an instagram like application for iOS using Xcode and objective-c. I looked around but I could not figure out how Instagram implemented the following grid feed:

https://debsphuong.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/5-volleyball-hashtag-page.jpg

Any insights would be greatly appreciated it. Thank you

Comment: probably an uicollectionview with three columns. First section being implemented differently than the other ones. All cells in a collection view can have different styling, depending on your needs. Look up UICollectionViewDataSource.

Comment: @ØyvindHauge thank you for the help! I will look into it. Now as for the infinite scrolling, do you have any insights on that? thank you in advance

Comment: There's no "infinite" scrolling, they're just fetching more content from the network programmatically as you scroll down

Answer (score 1):

That is a UICollection view. when you tap on the button to turn that grid into a single column grid, the cells are resized to the width of the view and reloaded again.

Comment: thank you for the help! I will look into it. Now as for the infinite scrolling, do you have any insights on that? thank you in advance

Comment: If you mean the main feed in twitter then that would be a UITableView with data being lazy loaded in. If this is a satisfactory answer then please mark it as so :)